# Is there a way to speed up dryscrape eval_script() execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web-scraping, dryscrape

I am scraping a web page using dryscrape (as I need the javascript rendered parts) and I am using eval_script() to suppress some javascript based error checking on the page. This script that I'm suppressing is basically an `onkeyup` listener that I need to avoid as it makes it mandatory for the user to select options from a dropdown only.
This is the eval script -

```
session.eval_script("$('#input_elem').removeAttr('onblur onclick onkeyup');")
```

Now the overall scraping takes a much longer time as compared to my other implementation of a page on the same domain which doesn't require any javascript modifications (hence without eval_script()).

I did a bit of profiling using `time.time()` to see where the script was slowing and indeed, its taking a long time on the eval_script() step(s). Here are the results -

```
Starting to access at  0.00997018814087
Visited page  https://*****/***.aspx    1.30053019524
First eval script run done  5.97628307343
Second eval script run done  9.61053919792
xpath 1  9.6632771492
xpath 2  9.7702870369
xpath 3  9.90402317047
xpath of button to be clicked  9.91756606102
Button clicked  9.97191905975
Second page visited  10.4508111477
Loop 1 else  10.4525721073
xpath 4  10.5330061913
xpath 5  10.6111950874
xpath 6  10.6918411255
xpath 7  10.7721481323
Range begins  10.8208150864
3
Range ends  13.0008580685
```

Although when I'm looping through the table elements, it is taking about 2 seconds, but the two eval_script() steps, combined, are taking about 8 seconds.
When I do this in the Chrome dev tools console, the same scripts run in an instant.
Why is the dryscrape implementation taking so much time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery in eval_script() seems to be the culprit. I was able to reduce the script execution time significantly using plain javascript -

```
session.eval_script("document.getElementById('input_elem')").removeAttribute('onblur');
```

I had to use two lines for two separate attribute removal steps on the same element.

These are my profiling logs now -

```
Starting to access at  0.0151550769806
Visited page  https://*****/***.aspx    1.73412919044
First eval script run done  1.77594304085
First eval script part 2 run done  1.81522011757
Second eval script run done  1.85607099533
xpath 1  1.94704914093
xpath 2  2.03846216202
xpath 3  2.13886809349
xpath of button to be clicked  2.26395010948
Button clicked  2.27277112007
Second page visited  3.30618906021
Loop 1 else  3.38708400726
xpath 4  3.46828198433
xpath 5  3.54840707779
xpath 6  3.63034701347
xpath 7  3.7106590271
Range begins  3.75155210495
3
Range ends  5.91926407814
```

Even now, each step in the `range` loop is taking about 0.7 seconds which I'm aiming to reduce further.